# CakePHP Convert SQL To Paginate

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I have an SQL statement that returns the results I want, however I need to paginate these reults and have been having trouble the past couple days trying to get the query converted into $this->paginate

I am working with two tables that have a habtm relationship; items and item_owns. item_owns table contains 3 columns: id, item_id and user_id, while the items table contains id, collection_id, and name.

SQL that returns results I need:

```
SELECT it.id, it.name, COALESCE(count,0) as count 
FROM items as it 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT count(ito.item_id) as count, ito.item_id 
    FROM item_owns as ito 
    WHERE ito.user_id='4ffb9027-8c0c-4086-a13e-01a0cab1739a' 
    GROUP BY ito.item_id
) as ct ON ct.item_id = it.id
WHERE it.collection_id='4fc923f5-0a58-453f-9507-0c0c86106d80';
```

The below snippet gets me close, however I end up having to perform the counting of item_owns by user_id (grouped by item_id) outside the paginate function which means I can't sort based on the count...

```
$this->paginate = array(
'limit' => 5,
            'conditions' => array('Item.collection_id'=> $id ),
            'fields' => array('Item.id', 'Item.collection_id', 'Item.name'),
            'contain' => array(
                'ItemOwn'=>array(
                    'fields' => array('ItemOwn.id, ItemOwn.item_id, ItemOwn.user_id'),
                    'conditions' => array('ItemOwn.user_id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')),

                    )
                )
            );
```

I've also tried using 'joins' => array(), but not sure how I specify the "count" call in the fields array

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 5,
    'fields' => array('Item.id', 'Item.collection_id', 'Item.name', 'count(ItemOwn.item_id)'),
    'conditions' => array('Item.collection_id'=> $id, 'ItemOwn.user_id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id') ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'alias' => 'ItemOwn',
            'table' => 'item_owns',
            'foreign_key' => false,
            'type' => 'LEFT OUTER',
            'conditions' => array('ItemOwn.item_id = Item.id'),
            'group' => 'ItemOwn.item_id'
            )
        )
    );
```

I suspect I may need to use custom pagination function, but again I'm not sure where some of the JOINs and conditions would go in that...

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!
Thanks
MK

Answer (score 0):

You're using contain which is good, but you should also be using Cake's [counter cache](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) for the counts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have considered using counter cache, but that would mean creating a new table in my DB, as there can be duplicate item_ids in item_owns each with a unique own item_owns.id. That is because the same item may be owned by a user multiple times, but they are different instances/copies of that item.

Comment: Hmm, you could try creating another temporary relationship between the tables youneed to use while counting which would just be used for that. Like using the bindModel() function before the paginate. But I do think you might still be able to use counter cache, even in your situation as long as you linked it to the HABTM join table.

Comment: Thanks... will give it a try. It may just be worth it to create new table with counter cache for the amount of effort I seem to be giving this :) ...was thinking using that new table as the "parent" item_owns table and my original item_owns as containing all the "child" items that way I could count all the child items w/ same parent id and store that count in parent table. Will give some more thought though and try out some other possible alternatives. Thanks again for your input!

Comment: You're welcome, and good luck! Do post the solution you come up with :)